# Scrapy - Spiders taking too long to being shut down

Tags: python, scrapy, subprocess

Basically, I have a file named `spiders.py` in which I configure all my spiders and fire then all, using a single crawler. This is the source code of this file:

```
from scrapy import spiderloader
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from navigator import *


def main():
  settings = get_project_settings()
  spider_loader = spiderloader.SpiderLoader.from_settings(settings)
  process = CrawlerProcess(settings=settings)
  for spider_name in spider_loader.list():
      process.crawl(spider_name)

  process.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to fire this spiders from another script, using `subprocess` module, and after 5 minutes of execution, turning down all spiders (using only one `SIGTERM`). The file responsible for this objective is `monitor.py`:

```
from time import sleep
import os
import signal
import subprocess

def main():
  spiders_process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "spiders.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      shell=False, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
  sleep(300)
  os.killpg(spiders_process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

When the main thread wake up, the terminal says `2018-07-19 21:45:09 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGTERM, shutting down gracefully. Send again to force`
. But even after this message, the spiders continue to scrap the web pages. What I doing wrong?

*OBS* : It is possible to fire all spiders inside `spiders.py` without blocking the main process?

Comment: If you want to stop infidelity the spider you will have to send a second `SIGTERM` signal. otherwise, it will finish all pending requests before closing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when scrapy receives a SIGTERM it tries to shutdown gracefully by first waiting to finished all sent/scheduled requests. Your best bet is to either limit the number or concurrent requests so it finishes quicker (`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`/`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` are 16 and 8 respectively by default) or to send two SIGTERM's to instruct scrapy to do unclean immediate exit.

> OBS : It is possible to fire all spiders inside spiders.py without blocking the main process?

`process.start()` starts twisted reactor (twisted main event loop) which is a blocking call, to circumvent it and run more code after the reactor has been started you can schedule a function be run inside the loop. First snippet from this manual should give you an idea: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/time.html.

However, if you go that way, you must make sure that the code you schedule have to also be non blocking, otherwise when you pause the execution of the loop for too long bad things can start happening. So things like `time.sleep()` must be rewritten in a twisted equivalent.